# Animate SVG viewBox change

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, velocity.js

I am currently using velocity.js to control some animation on an SVG drawing I am creating. It is interactive with the user, so when a click happens in certain parts, the picture might grow to the right or down. So far everything is working perfectly until the picture gets too big for the SVG box.

In those situations, I simply resize the viewBox to scale the image.

```
svgDoc.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + svgDocWidth + " " + svgDocHeight);
```

This works, but it doesn't look great because it isn't animated. It just jumps to the new size. Is there a way to animate with velocity.js a viewBox change?

I've tried this approach:

```
$viewBox = $(svgDoc.viewBox);
$viewBox.velocity({height: svgDocHeight, width: svgDocWidth});
```

But that doesn't do anything.

Is this beyond what velocity.js can support?

**Solution on 2015-11-21**

@Ian gave the solution I eventually used. It ended up looking like this:

```
var origHeight = this.svgDoc.viewBox.animVal.height;
var origWidth = this.svgDoc.viewBox.animVal.width;

var docHeight = this.SvgHeight();
var docWidth = this.SvgWidth();

if ((origHeight != docHeight) || (origWidth != docWidth))
{
    var deltaHeight = docHeight - origHeight;
    var deltaWidth = docWidth - origWidth;

    $(this.svgDoc).velocity(
    { 
        tween: 1 
    },
    { 
        progress: function(elements, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue)
        {
            var newWidth = origWidth + complete * deltaWidth;
            var newHeight = origHeight + complete * deltaHeight;
            elements[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + newWidth + ' ' + newHeight); 
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SMIL is being deprecated in Chrome (please correct me if I'm wrong), so I'm guessing there will be increasing reliance on other methods.

There's no reason you can't use velocity, but with your own calculations and the progress/tweenValue parameter, eg something a bit like this...

```
$("#mysvg").velocity(
    { tween: 200 },
    { progress: animViewbox }
)

function animViewbox (elements, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue) {
     elements[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + tweenValue + ' ' + tweenValue);  
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/18Lpxzp1/5/)

Comment: There are libraries/polyfills that will add SMIL back in if Chrome removes it.

Answer (score 9):

You can animate a viewBox smoothly via SMIL. Like this...

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="0 0 400 400" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="green" />
</svg>
```